# How to fetch data from pList in Label

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, plist

I have a `RegistrationController` screen to store `email-id` ,`password`,`DOB`,`Height`,`Weight` and  `logininController` screen to match `email-id` and `password` to log-in purpose.

Now, In some `third` screen I have to fetch only the `Height`,`Weight`  from the plist of the logged-in user  to display it on the  label.now if I Store the values of `email-id` and `password` in from `LoginViewController` in string and call it in the new screen to match if matches then gives `Height`,`Weight` ..if it corrects then how to fetch `Height`,`Weight` from the plist of the same one.

How can I fetch from the stored plist in a string?

Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray*)readFromPlist
 {
   NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XYZ.plist"];

   NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

   NSArray *valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

   return valueArray;

 }



- (void)authenticateCredentials {
    NSMutableArray *plistArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self readFromPlist]];

    for (int i = 0; i< [plistArray count]; i++)
    {
        id object = [plistArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

            if ([[objDict objectForKey:@"pass"] isEqualToString:emailTextFeild.text] && [[objDict objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:passwordTextFeild.text])
            {
                NSLog(@"Correct credentials");
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"INCorrect credentials");
        } else {
             NSLog(@"Error! Not a dictionary");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get whole value from your plist file after that store this `NSArray` into `NSMutableArray` and get the value with its `objectAtIndex` and `valueForKey` property..see whole example bellow..

**UPDATE :**

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:contentArray];

    for (int i = 0; i< [yourArray count]; i++)
    {
        id object = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *objDict = (NSDictionary *)object;

           yourLableWeight.text = [[objDict objectForKey:@"Weight"];// set index with your requirement
         yourLableHeight.text = [[objDict objectForKey:@"Height"];

    }
```

hope this help you...

Comment: where to use this code in Logincontroller or in thirdview where I need to fetch the data

Comment: ok as u r saying to store in the NSMutableArray but how plist be know that it is from the same logged in user ....because there are multiple logged-in users in the plist

Comment: see dude when you loged in at that time some unique id of user you get and from this just get that plist which also under the user id .. and for that you must create good design to use it for every use...

Comment: ya I have reached to the step to check user-id from the third page...it works fine...now when to get weight and height it crash..

Comment: just check that what you get from plist?? if its dictionary then use its propery and check that it not get null value.. also check  the key name with height and weight are stay in there or not dude..

Comment: sorry I dont know how to set the index..how to give value

Comment: @SameSungVsIphone also check that the Dictionary must contain plist objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary). And dictionary keys must be NSString objects

Comment: my plist is somehow like this image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873968/credential-match-from-plist/13874224#comment19109319_13874224 here item0,item1,item2.... consist of the `title,pass,height,weight,dob`  and i used the same above code to read plist

Comment: hey use updated answer dude i skip one [ from the code dude.. sorry and it just like a array in which you give array index and key of array dude..

Comment: yes exactly i post comment about it dude.. if here system not found any record then it ll crashed .. here use the structer of dictionary from your previos answer same like with you whole data and retrive this two values with its both key name.. just modify some code dude...

Comment: hey you wont belive ..just now...i thought the same and tried in my code...and worked fine....and i was goin to reply you...and u answer the same one..

Comment: but i did it little different way... i matched my logged-in and just below code...i used  yourLableWeight.text = [[objDict objectForKey:@"Weight"];// set index with your requirement
         yourLableHeight.text = [[objDict objectForKey:@"Height"];

Comment: what a coincidence dude.. and whats wrong here?? its work fine right??

Comment: one basic question.. string1=[[objDict objectForKey:@"Height"];   say it comes 20...ok...now if multiply ...(string1*0.02) its not possible ryt...because nsstring * double....

Comment: possible dude but using double or float you can convert it and then store it dude..

Comment: @SameSungVsIphone hey use this code dude...     NSString *string1 = @"20";
    float fl = [string1 floatValue]*0.02;
    string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",fl];
    NSLog(@"\n\n String 1 %@",string1);

Comment: yes dude.. i just give you an example for understand dude.. :)

Comment: problem problem ..what i did  `float f1=[string floatValue]; float a=(f1*0.009); label.text=(@"%f",a)`... in last step...error...now how to convert float to string

Comment: oh dude use stringwithFormate mate.. ;) like this label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",a];

Comment: expression problem again-> float minutes= ((10.0/60) % 60......but modules(%) cant be come in float...what to do

Comment: hey dude i will post code about it otherwise search about it with iPhone sdk character dude..

Answer (score 1):

When you enter credentials on login screen to check when it match the credentials with the fetched plist then pass that plist to the next controller. Do something like this

```
UserViewController *controller = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundel:nil];
[controller setUserDictionary:yourPlistDictionary];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

in UserViewController you would have a NSDictionary instance to store the data to show, hope that will help you

Comment: no it will push me to the UserViewController ...I dont want to push....I want when I am in UserViewController then i want to check for logged-in user and fetch particular user height and weight

Comment: your question was you at LoginViewController you need to match the credentials then on 3rd screen you need to show the looged in user's hight and widht right, if you are managing separate plist for every user then why don't you save that plist after matching username and password and send that plist to 3rd view controller which contains all the data of user